# Unity 3d How to make the player to stay at the target position after the animation completes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

Hello I have the Problem that the Animation Pos not stay. I need this for a Dodge(Combat) system. Root Motion Doesn't work!

.

Comment: Please before asking your first question, [Take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This can be sound boring, but StackOverflow is a professional community. So, if you want other people's help, first take your time, and clearly explain your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's root motion and how it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312228/whats-root-motion-and-how-it-works)

Answer (score 0):

You can make another state in animation and make your animation to go to that state. In script don't let player move when animation is in that state.

Return to idle state whenever you want to make things normal again.

Other way to do is use other animations libs (like leantween) and make a callback after animation ends.